# Insert in middle of a Object in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sorting, insert

I have a object and I need insert a object in the middle.

I tried a push and sort, but dosen´t work...

this is my code:

```
let myObject = [
{
    'item1' : 'string1',
    'item2' : 'string2',
    'item3' : 'string3',
    'item4' : 'string4',
    'item5' : 'string5',
    'item6' : 'string6',
    'item7' : 'string7',
    'item8' : 'string8',
    'item10' : 'string10',
    'item11' : 'string11',
    'item12' : 'string12',
    'item14' : 'string14',
    'item15' : 'string15'
},
{
    'item16' : 'string16',
    'item17' : 'string17',
    'item18' : 'string18',
    'item19' : 'string19',
    'item20' : 'string20',
    'item21' : 'string21',
    'item22' : 'string22',
    'item23' : 'string23',
    'item25' : 'string25',
    'item26' : 'string26',
    'item27' : 'string27',
    'item29' : 'string29',
    'item30' : 'string30'
    }
]

myObject[0].item9 = 'string9'
myObject[0].item13 = 'string13'

console.log(myObject[0])

//OUTPUT
// {
//     item1: 'string1',
//     item2: 'string2',
//     item3: 'string3',
//     item4: 'string4',
//     item5: 'string5',
//     item6: 'string6',
//     item7: 'string7',
//     item8: 'string8',
//     item10: 'string10',
//     item11: 'string11',
//     item12: 'string12',
//     item14: 'string14',
//     item15: 'string15',
//     item9: 'string9',
//     item13: 'string13'
//   }

myObject = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myObject[0]).sort())
console.log(myObject)
//OUTPUT
//   {
//     item1: 'string1',
//     item10: 'string10',
//     item11: 'string11',
//     item12: 'string12',
//     item13: 'string13',
//     item14: 'string14',
//     item15: 'string15',
//     item2: 'string2',
//     item3: 'string3',
//     item4: 'string4',
//     item5: 'string5',
//     item6: 'string6',
//     item7: 'string7',
//     item8: 'string8',
//     item9: 'string9'
//   }
```

How can I do that OUTPUT:
{
item1: 'string1',
item2: 'string2',
item3: 'string3',
item4: 'string4',
item5: 'string5',
item6: 'string6',
item7: 'string7',
item8: 'string8',
item9: 'string9',
item10: 'string10',
item11: 'string11',
item12: 'string12',
item13: 'string13',
item14: 'string14',
item15: 'string15'
}

Comment: Properties on an object do not give you control of the order.  They are recorded in the order added and there is no way to "insert" one somewhere in the middle of the order after the others have already been added afterwards.  Typically, an array should be used for ordered data, not properties on an object.

Comment: A hack would be to create a brand new object and add all the properties to it in the order you want them and then use that object in place of the original.  But, really if order is something you care about, use an array instead!  That gives you direct insertion capabilities, in fact you can even sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a solution that came to my head but i'm sure that there is a more efficient and sexy solution to this problem. The problem is that you would need to convert it back to an object from the array. Should work, I didn't came to test it just wrote it quick in my notepad :).

```
   let myObject = [
    {
        'item1' : 'string1',
        'item2' : 'string2',
        'item3' : 'string3',
        'item4' : 'string4',
        'item5' : 'string5',
        'item6' : 'string6',
        'item7' : 'string7',
        'item8' : 'string8',
        'item10' : 'string10',
        'item11' : 'string11',
        'item12' : 'string12',
        'item14' : 'string14',
        'item15' : 'string15'
    },
    {
        'item16' : 'string16',
        'item17' : 'string17',
        'item18' : 'string18',
        'item19' : 'string19',
        'item20' : 'string20',
        'item21' : 'string21',
        'item22' : 'string22',
        'item23' : 'string23',
        'item25' : 'string25',
        'item26' : 'string26',
        'item27' : 'string27',
        'item29' : 'string29',
        'item30' : 'string30'
        }
    ]
    
    var result = Object.keys(myObject[0]).map(e => ({item: e, string: myObject[0][e]}))
    
    result.splice(8, 0, {item: 'item9', word: 'string9'});
    
    result.splice(12, 0, {item: 'item13', word: 'string13'});
    
    //result would be an array of objects with params 'item' and 'array'
    
    console.log(result)
```